# How to align page contents with the backside of the printed document?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

So I want to make help cards for my students, but I am struggling while trying to find a smart solution to do that (without having to print a document and measuring manually and setting all vertical pages on the backside manually).

Minimal working example could look something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% front side of the document
\textbf{Help for number 1}

Explanation\\
text\\
across\\
some\\
lines

\vspace*{5mm}

\textbf{Help for number 2}

Explanation text\\
across different\\
amount of lines


\newpage
% back side of the document
\huge{Help for number 1}

\vspace*{3cm} %not sure how much I actually need. Can I calculate this automatically?

\huge{Help for number 2}
\end{document}
```

Untill now I have just written the backside by hand on the printed document. But there has to be a smart solution. Can you help me (and my students) achieve this?

Comment: `\huge{Help for number 1}` makes the rest of the document huge, not `Help for number 1`

Comment: There is  a `flacards` class and also a `flashcards` class for this purpose.